# How to use forEach with multiple traversables?

Tags: haskell, ihp

I am not able to find a way where I can use forEach with multiple traversables meaning a function that is `fn :: _ -> _ -> Html` rather than just `fn :: _ -> Html` and I don't think the documentation shows a way.

I have tried: `{forEach traversable1 (fn traversable2)}`, this doesn't really work, but it does for a non-traversable. I also tried something similar to [this](https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/api-docs/IHP-HaskellSupport.html#v:forEachWithIndex), so `let tvsbl :: ([_], [_])` ... `{forEach tsbl fn}`, that hasn't worked either.

Comment: Do you want parallel iteration/zippy behavior or nested iteration/producty behavior? For the former, there isn't really a common accepted class (though there are packages that have tried to become this); for the latter, you can simply write a nested loop by calling `forEach` twice.

Comment: @DanielWagner Parallel iteration, similar to a Post, comment relationship where i iterate both of them at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `zip`:

```hs
[hsx|
    {forEach (zip traversable1 traversable2) renderBoth}
|]
    where
        renderBoth item1 item2 = [hsx|
            <i>{item1}</i>
        |]
```

Comment: Thank you, I would say to add a type signature in the function such that it can be: `(_,  _) -> Html; renderBoth (item1, item2) = ...`